# Use of "template<>" for static members

Tags: c++

I came across some code that has confused me. I have distilled the confusion down to a simple case

```
template<typename T>
struct S
{
    T member;
    static const size_t size;
};

struct U { int i; };
typedef S<U> US_t;

template<> const size_t US_t::size = sizeof(U);
```

Q1: Why do I need the "`template<>`" on that last line, since `US_t` is fully described?

The code I actually came across - which compiles - has the equivalent of this:

```
template<>template<> const size_t US_t::size = sizeof(U);
```

I'm pretty sure it was a cut-and-paste error that wasn't caught because it compiled.
Q2: Is this valid? If so, why?
[I notice that codepad.org will compile the code with "`template<>template<>`".]

Comment: This is called a *template specialization*, it provides a different value for `S<U>::size` than for generic `S<T>::size`. [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-specialization).  (IDK about the double template<> ...)

Comment: possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927196/double-template-in-template-specialization

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your typedef as a macro that's expanded at compile time instead of pre-processor time.

Then without the `template<>` you'd have

```
const size_t S<U>::size = sizeof(U);
```

And that's not a valid syntax, because you're doing a template specialization